# How can I make my method return a string value yet remain an asynchronous method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the method below that is returning this error:

```
Error   CS1983  The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task<T>, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, or IAsyncEnumerator<T>
```

But when I click on the error number link in Visual Studio, it takes me to a Microsoft website that just says:

```
Sorry, we don't have specifics on this C# error
```

Here is the method:

```
private async String SaveAIguess(IFormFile file)
{
    var picture = GetFile(file.FileName);
    await StorageService.Save(picture, file.OpenReadStream());

    var resourceUrl = Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
    return resourceUrl;
}
```

Is there a way to make it asynchronous and still be able to return the resourceUrl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous methods must return either `Task`, `Task<?>`, or `void`. If you change your return type to `Task<string>` it should work as desired. Of course, any method calling your async method must also be asynchronous or it must call it like `SaveAIguess(dat).Result` to make it synchronous.

So your final code will look like

```cs
private async Task<String> SaveAIguess(IFormFile file)
{
    var picture = GetFile(file.FileName);
    await StorageService.Save(picture, file.OpenReadStream());

    var resourceUrl = Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
    return resourceUrl;
}
```

And it can be called like this in another async method:

```cs
var str = await SaveAIguess(dat);
```

Or in a synchronous method

```cs
var str = SaveAIGuess(dat).Result
```

Answer (score 3):

Make it return `Task<string>`:

```
private async Task<string> SaveAIguess(IFormFile file)
{
    var picture = GetFile(file.FileName);
    await StorageService.Save(picture, file.OpenReadStream());

    var resourceUrl = Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
    return resourceUrl;
}
```

`async` methods either have no return value or anything that can be encapsulated in a `Task<>`. It's why to get the actual value you do:

```
var val = await SaveAIguess(file);
```

`await` basically "unwraps" the `Task` and gives you your `string`.

Answer (score -2):

Yes:

```
private async Task<String> SaveAIguess(IFormFile file)
```